# mutt weird action

Tags: command-line, email, mutt

I wrote a little script to send multiple mails from a list with differents subjects.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while read -a line
 do
 mailadd=${line[0]}
 subject=${line[1]} 

 mutt -s `echo $subject` `echo $mailadd` < /home/emanuele/testomail.txt

 done < prova.txt
```

The scripts works fine and sends the mails, but mutt tell me that he needs a `-s` option.

```
mutt: option requires an argument -- 's'
Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)
```

I don't understand why the script works fine but mutt exit with an error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you writing \`echo $variable\`?  Why not just "$variable"?  Most likely your variables are empty, and mutt just sees:
`mutt -s < /home/emanuele/testomail.txt`

Comment: it is the same thing. any way i said that the script works fine. all the mails are sent and arrives to the mail server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `` `echo $subject` `` is a convoluted way of writing `$subject` (except that it mangles the value a bit more if it contains whitespace or `\[*?`, because `$subject` outside quotes is treated as a whitespace-separated list of wildcard patterns, and then the result of the whole command substitution is again treated as a whitespace-separated list of wildcard patterns).

The only way for your command to result in this error is if `` `echo $subject` `echo $mailadd` `` is empty. This happens only when both `` `echo $subject` `` and `` `echo $mailadd` `` consist only of whitespace, which in turns happens only if both variables `subject` and `mailadd` are empty (plus a few oddball cases, such as `subject` being the character `?` and the current directory containing a file whose name is a single space). So most likely you have some blank lines in your input file.

You should always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions (`"$somevar"`, `"$(somecommand)"`) unless you really mean the values of the variables to be interpreted as whitespace-separated lists of file wildcard patterns.

```
mutt -s "$subject" "$mailaddr" <~/testeomail.txt
```

If there's a blank line in the input file, skip it.

```
while read -a line; do
  mailadd=${line[0]}
  subject=${line[1]}
  if [ -z "$subject" ]; then continue; fi
  mutt -s "$subject" "$mailadd" < /home/emanuele/testomail.txt
done < prova.txt
```